# How does JSON handle special characters in objects?

Tags: json

I am creating a JSON parser. I am almost complete, all I need to do is wrap up how special character should be parsed if inserted into an object. I am looking at the builtin version of JSON right now.

```
Str3 = '{\r\n"glossary": {\n"title": "example glossary"}}';
JSON.parse(Str3)
>>>Object {glossary: Object}
```

It appears as though JSON.parse is ignoring the special characters altogether. Is this actually what is happening? Or is there something more that is occurring under the hood?

Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: Any particular reason you're writing your own JSON parser?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the standard [ECMA-404: The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf):

> Insignificant  whitespace  is  allowed  before  or  after  any  token.  The  whitespace  characters  are:  character 
>   tabulation  (U+0009),  line  feed  (U+000A),  carriage  return  (U+000D),  and  space  (U+0020).

and by [JSON.org](http://json.org/):

> Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens.

When you constructed `Str3` in JavaScript, you used the syntax `\r` and `\n`. This [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) is converted into the carriage return (U+000D) and line feed (U+000A) characters, respectively, by your JavaScript interpreter:

```
String.fromCharCode(0x000D) === '\r'
>>> true
'\r' === '\u000d'
>>> true

String.fromCharCode(0x000A) === '\n'
>>> true
'\n' === '\u000a'
>>> true
```

To have a conforming JSON parser, you must allow the whitespace characters to be present between tokens of the input.